# Vue Js Login Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a registration system in Vue.js and need some advice on what is best practise to do so.

Lets say that this is my form. I want all the action take place under /login. (I know it would be easier to do it through router :) ).

What is the best practise to navigate through the content? Would it be better if I separate my forms through components? Is the way of setting a var of page and set it to what I need to display and show it with `v-show`? Or anything else would be much appreciated.

Find below a dummy example of what i need, to get an idea.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    login: {
          login: '',
          password: ''
        },
        forgot: {
          email: '',
        },
        page: 'login',
  },
  methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        return true;
      },
      someAction() {
        return true;
      },
      anotherAction(){
        return true;
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="login">

    <form v-show="page == 'login'" @submit.prevent>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <input type="text" v-model="login.login" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" v-model="login.password" placeholder="Password" />

      <div style="margin: 10px 0;">
        <button @click="page = 'forgot'">
          Forgot password?
        </button>
      </div>

      <button v-on:click="onSubmit">Log in</button>
    </form>


    <form  v-show="page == 'forgot'"  @submit.prevent>
      <h2>Forgot password</h2>

      <input type="text" v-model="forgot.email"> -

      <button @click="page = 'fEmail'">Forgot Email</button>

      <div>
        <button @click="someAction">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>


    <form  v-show="page == 'fEmail'"  @submit.prevent>
      <h2>Forgot email</h2>

      <p>Some content here</p>

      <div>
        <button @click="page = 'login'">
          Back to login
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Also a fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/wx5bty2p/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

some suggestions:

1. Having separate pages for each flow would be better, one for the login, one for the recover password, one for the register, etc, because you can share the exact URL to the user (will be easier with vue router)
2. If the flow is very small, you can have a parent component that handles the main flow and several children components for each flow (forms), you can use Vue dynamic component https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components
3. You need to think about how are you going to handle the authentication (json web tokes/ simple password, oauth2), that will be a really important thing before doing the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment was really helpful. I already have my authentication set with Oauth2. I just wanted to add the forgot password functionality but wasn't sure which approach was better.